# Converting JavaScript to TypeScript in Nuxt3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxt.js

I am using the Nuxt 3.10.0 version and Vue3. I want to convert my Nuxt3 project, which initially used JavaScript, to TypeScript. Can I simply change `<script setup>` to `<script setup lang='ts'>` in every .vue file? Are there other configurations I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

setting `lang="ts"` works fine. If you're working with TypeScript in a Nuxt project, you'll want to set up a `tsconfig.json` file to configure it properly. Nuxt takes care of creating this file for you automatically when you install a new project."

Comment: so there's no need to install @nuxt/typescript-build and @nuxt/types following  [this guide](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/) right?  I guess that's only for Nuxt2? 

Thanks!